# Number of newtheorem overlaps with newtheorem in the Appendix

Tags: theorems

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\textbf{Beweis}}
\newtheorem{Satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{code}[Satz]{MATLAB-Code} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Anhang}
\renewcommand\thesection{\hspace{-1em}}
\sectionmark{Anhang}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
\begin{code}
...
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the number of the code overlaps with the word MATLAB-Code in the appendix (Anhang). I guess it has something to do that there is no section number for the appendix. How can I fix that?
If I write

```
\newtheorem{code}{MATLAB-Code}
```

then the number of the newtheorem and the word MATLAB-Code don't overlap, but then the codes get numberes from 1 on instead of using the section number.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can provide a working example illustrating the problem.  Removing `[Satz]` from the above code makes it compilable, but also does not show any problem with overlapping numbers.

Comment: I did exact the same for  \newtheorem{Bem}[Satz]{Bemerkung} and there it works. My guess is that MATLAB-Code is too long.

Comment: There is something you are not telling us. This includes something in the document sets up the count `Satz`, and possibly theorem related packages you are loading...

Comment: you are right, if i delete [Satz] it's working. That's exact how I wanted it, thanks.

Comment: But then the number of MATLAB-code starts with one, but I want that the number is the chapter number.1, chapter number.2 and so on.

Comment: Then have a look at `Satz` what it different in that definition in comparison to the definition to `code`? Hint: look at the end.

Comment: Also note that `article` does not use chapters, but sections. And what on earth, are you doing with that `\renewcommand\thesection{\hspace{-1em}}`? *that* is really bad coding.

Comment: I wanted to get rid of the section number of the Appendix (Anhang). With that command it works, but I guess that's why 'MATLAB-Code' and the code number overlap.

Comment: Oh, yes. the `[section]` part of `Satz` incorporates `\thesection` to number the `Satz`. Another lesson is, don't hide stuff in our minimal example

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask how remove section numbers of theorem like items in the appendix.  Redefining `\thesection` to `\hspace{-1em}` causes you many problems as you found out.

Instead to remove section numbering of these elements in the appendix use the `chngcntr` packages's function `\counterwithout`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newtheorem{Satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{code}[Satz]{MATLAB-Code} 

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{Satz}
  Theorem text.
\end{Satz}

\section*{Anhang}

\counterwithout{Satz}{section}
\sectionmark{Anhang}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
\begin{code}
...
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use this code it still shows the section number of the Apeendix in the Header. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: The above code produces no header, so you will have to tell us how you make your headers. That is probably best done as a separate question.  But have a look around this site for related questions.